# How to calculate number of rows obtained after a join, a filter or a write without using count function - Pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I am using PySpark to join, filter and write large dataframe to a csv.

After each filter join or write, I count the number of lines with df.count().

However, counting the number of rows mean reloading the data and re-perform the various operations.

How could I count the number of lines during each different operations without reloading and calculate as with df.count() ?

I am aware that the cache function could be a solution to not reload and recalculate but I am looking for another solution as it's not always the best one.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please provide some source code of your problem and attempted solution.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why not look at the spark UI to see get a feel for what's happening instead of using Count?  This might help you get a feel without actually doing counts.  Jobs/Tasks can help you find the bottlenecks.  The SQL tab can help you look at your plan to understand what's actually happening.

If you want something better than count.

[countApprox](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.RDD.countApprox.html) is cheaper.(RDD level tooling)  You should be caching if you are going to count it and then use it the dataframe again after. Actually count is sometimes use to force caching.

Comment: Indeed, Spark UI is much better to find bottleneck rather than count.
However, I wish to use counts to create statistics following the execution of a spark job. Hence the use of a count at each step since I need the value in my python script.

Comment: You may wish to look at accumulators.  They also report in the spark UI and where built for this type of counting. https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/rdd-programming-guide.html#accumulators

Comment: I would just take one more look at the query plan (SQL tab in spark UI). It does contain metrics on output # of rows.  This would be a lot lighter and less impactful to your jobs performance.